# Gaps at curve that represents the solution of system of equations as a function of parameter

Tags: equation-solving

```
Manipulate[{
  Quiet[sol = 
     Solve[{K1*P*L == PL, K2*P*L == LP, K3*PL*L == LPL, 
       P0 == P + PL + LP + LPL, r*P0 == L + PL + LP + 2*LPL}, {P, L, 
       LP, PL, LPL}]][[2]];
  complex[x_] := LPL /. sol[[2]] /. r -> x;
  Plot[{complex[r]}, {r, 0.1, 6}]
  },

 {K1, 1001, 10000},
 {K2, 1000, 10000},
 {K3, 1000, 10000},
 {P0, 0.1, 1}
 ]
```

If `K1 == K2 == K3` we have nice curve otherwise there are gaps at curve. what's wrong?

Comment: The solution is complex at places

Comment: Better also add `TrackedSymbols -> {K1, K2, K3, P0}` to prevent your `Manipulate`from being busy all the time.

Comment: Related: [(17202)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17202/121),
[(58976)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58976/121),
[(65084)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65084/121),
[(69976)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69976/121)

Answer (score 4):

Try!

```
(*First solve and store the symbolic data*)
val = LPL /.First@Solve[{K1*P*L == PL, K2*P*L == LP, K3*PL*L == LPL, 
  P0 == P + PL + LP + LPL, r*P0 == L + PL + LP + 2*LPL}, {P, L,LP, PL, LPL}];
(*
  + Define a function that evaluates the symbolic expression given
    numerical value to the parameters.
  + We use DifInd with default value 0 we can compute the d-th derivative in
    case of DifInd=d.
*)
complex[rVal_, K1Val_, K2Val_, K3Val_, P0Val_, DifInd_: 0] := 
Re@With[{r = rVal, K1 = K1Val, K2 = K2Val, K3 = K3Val, P0 = P0Val, 
índex = DifInd}, (Evaluate@D[val, {r, índex}])];
Needs["PlotLegends`"];
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[{
complex[r, K1, K2, K3, P0],
complex[r, K1, K2, K3, P0, 1],
complex[r, K1, K2, K3, P0, 4]
}], {r, 0.1, 6},
ImageSize -> 600,
Frame -> True,
PlotStyle -> {Thick, {Red, Thick, Dashed}, Green},
PlotLegend -> {"f(x)", "f'(x)", "f''''(x)"},
LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4}],
{K1, 1001, 10000}, {K2, 1000,10000}, {K3, 1000, 10000}, {P0, 0.1, 1}]
```

[image: Manipulate[] interface]

I use `Re` to plot only the real part of `complex`. I noticed that it also has an imaginary part with very small magnitude.

Comment: Cool! Thank you! I tried to plot as well derivative of complex using following code: Plot[{Evaluate[complex[r, K1, K2, K3, P0]], 
   Hold[Evaluate@D[complex[r, K1, K2, K3, P0], r]]} // Release, {r, 
  0.1, 6}] without success. I'm still a newbie in mathematica, so I will be happy if you help me one more time.

Comment: @Philipp Here comes the help for one more time! I updated the answer to accommodate derivatives with in the definition of `complex`. You need to change the definition of the function itself. You cant perform the `D[]` inside `Plot` as `complex`was previously defined not be symbolic but only numeric inside `Plot`.