# Graphs Plotting Discontinuous

Tags: plotting, linear-algebra

I'm trying to plot a graph from the eigenvalues of a matrix I created. The graph shows with discontinuities in it and I was looking for some feedback.

Here's the code:

```
v1 = -4.01*Exp[I*(ka)/2];
v2 = -4.01*Exp[-I*(ka)/2];
v3 = -4.01*Exp[I*(ka)];
v4 = -4.01*Exp[-I*(ka)];
Eo = -8.97;

H = {{Eo, v1, 0, 0, 0, v4}, {v2, Eo, v2, 0, v3, 0},
   {0, v1, Eo, v4, 0, 0}, {0, 0, v3, Eo, v2, 0}, {0, v4, 0, v1, Eo, 
    v1}, {v3, 0, 0, 0, v2, Eo}};
MatrixForm[H]
bs = Eigenvalues[H];
Plot[bs, {(ka), -0.8, 0.8}]
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51776/how-get-eigenvectors-without-phase-jump http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/39747/how-to-plot-several-functions-without-jumping-multiple-eigenvalues-of-a-system

Answer (score 3):

Small numerical errors generate tiny imaginary parts-Solve it with:

```
Plot[bs // Chop, {(ka), -0.8, 0.8}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Eventually, answering @MarkMcClure's comment:

```
b[k_?NumericQ] := Eigenvalues[H /. ka -> k]; 
Plot[Quiet@Table[b[ka][[i]], {i, 6}], {(ka), -0.8, 0.8}, Evaluated -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

NB: The `Plot[Quiet@Table[...] ...,Evaluated -> True]` thing is a dirty trick to force colorization. Perhaps someone could come up with something cleaner.

Comment: But now, all the plots are the same color. Worse, the standard tricks involving `Evaluate`, `With`, or the `Evaluated` option all bring the discontinuities back, as `Chop` applied to non-numeric expressions just returns the expressions. I was only able to resolve this by generating the data and using `ListPlot`.

Comment: @MarkMcClure `b[k_?NumericQ] := Eigenvalues[H /. ka -> k];
Plot[Quiet@Table[b[ka][[i]], {i, 6}], {(ka), -0.8, 0.8}, 
 Evaluated -> True]`

Comment: Much faster, in fact!  I actually considered that but didn't try it as I figured it would be very slow as `Eigenvalues` is evaluated with each and every step. Evidently, the list `Root` objects take longer to evaluate than `Eigenvalues`, which might very well be evaluated numerically in this context.  Looks worth a +1!

Comment: @MarkMcClure Thanks, answer updated. Please see the last paragraph