# Gap in a continuous plot

Tags: plotting, bugs

Why do I get a gap in the plot below and how can I fix it?
(**If you are interested in it, you can see a new related question: [How to plot an implicit value funtion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/70033/how-to-plot-an-implicit-value-funtion), which is also a little chanlenging**)

Code:

```
Plot[InverseFunction[
   1 - 0.6*CDF[NormalDistribution[1, 0.3], #] - 
     0.4*CDF[NormalDistribution[3, 0.3], #] &][x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All, Exclusions -> None]
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Based on algohi's and a.g.'s answers I have tagged this with the bugs tag.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries,Hi Sjoerd, do you know how to report this bug to Wolfram? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ben : from Mathematica menus : Help -- Give feedback

Comment: Support@wolfram.com should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The function you wish to plot happens to be the `InverseSurvivalFunction` of  a `MixtureDistribution` with component distributions `NormalDistribution[1, 0.3]` and `NormalDistribution[3, 0.3]`, and weights `.6` and `.4`, respectively.

Using the built-in functions `MixtureDistribution` and `InverseSurvivalFunction` we get the desired result without an issue:

```
dist = MixtureDistribution[{6, 4}, {NormalDistribution[1, 0.3], NormalDistribution[3, 0.3]}]; 
Plot[InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

You can also use `InverseCDF` to get the same output:

```
Plot[InverseCDF[dist, 1 - x], {x, 0, 1}]
(* same picture *)
```

**Update:** Addressing the question in the comments:

> *I do need to characterize D[x*InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, x], x]*

Using the product rule and the [inverse function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem), you can define

```
derivative[x_] := (InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, y] +
     (x/(D[1 - CDF[dist, y], y] /. y -> InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, y]))) /. y -> x;

Column[Plot[#, {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 400] & /@
  {x InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, x], Evaluate@derivative[x]}]
```

[image]

Comment: It's very helpful. Btw, can we do operations on InverseSurvialFunction, like D[x*InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, x], x]? It seems it doesn't work. Thanks!

Comment: @ben, for the mixture distribution `dist`, `D[x*InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, x], x]` and `D[x*InverseCDF[dist, 1-x], x]` do not work; but they do work  for "simpler" distributions: for example, `D[InverseCDF[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], x]` and `D[InverseSurvivalFunction[NormalDistribution[0, 1], x], x]`.

Comment: I do need to characterize D[x*InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, x], x]. Do you have any suggestions which can remove the gap and also keep doing the derivation? Thanks.

Comment: @ben, since we do get a  closed form solution for `D[1 - CDF[dist, x], x]`, maybe you can use [Inverse Function Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem)? For example, `(1/(D[1 - CDF[dist, x], x] /. 
     x -> InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, x])) /.  x -> .5` gives `-2.00119`.

Comment: @ben, please see the update...

Comment: that's really helpful. You are the expert in Mathematica^-^. One more question, given profit function y*InverseSurvivalFunction[dist, x+y], for any x, I want to get the optimal value y*(x) to maximize the profit function. Do you know how to plot y*(x)? Really appreciate your work and help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19944/discussion-between-ben-and-kguler).

Answer (score 7):

You have complex numbers as a result in these ranges.

Check this:

```
Table[{i,
  InverseFunction[
    1 - 0.6*CDF[NormalDistribution[1, 0.3], #] -
      0.4*CDF[NormalDistribution[3, 0.3], #] &][i]}, {i, 0, 1, 0.01}]
```

The problem seems to be generated internally because of the real number in the function and also because of the fact that the plot uses a real number when sampling points for the plot. To see this behavior, look at these evolutions:

```
N[InverseFunction[
   1 - 6/10*CDF[NormalDistribution[1, 3/10], #] -
     4/10*CDF[NormalDistribution[3, 3/10], #] &][3/10]]

(*2.79765*)

InverseFunction[
  1 - 6/10*CDF[NormalDistribution[1, 3/10], #] -
    4/10*CDF[NormalDistribution[3, 3/10], #] &][0.3]

(*1.47655 + 0.475155 I*)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. How to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: ... complex roots are surprising, there are clearly real inverses. Could it be an issue with `InverseFunction`?

Comment: I have no idea. Maybe you are right. I will report it to Wolfram. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

We get a little insight to the "bug" by writing the CDF in terms of `Erfc`:

```
 InverseFunction[
       1 - 0.6*CDF[NormalDistribution[1, 0.3], #] - 
           0.4*CDF[NormalDistribution[3, 0.3], #] &][.3]
 InverseFunction[
       1 - 0.6 1/2 Erfc[2.3570226039551585` (1 - #)] - 
           0.4 1/2 Erfc[2.3570226039551585` (3 - #)] &][.3]
```

> 1.47655 + 0.475155 I
>
> 1.47655 + 0.475155 I

```
(1 - 0.6*1/2 Erfc[2.3570226039551585` (1 - #)] - 
   0.4*1/2 Erfc[2.3570226039551585` (3 - #)]) &@%
```

> 0.3 - 4.85056*10^-16 I

we see that while `CDF` can not take an imaginary argument, `Erfc` can and the erroneous result is indeed a complex valued inverse of the function.

### Edit -- a fix

it turns out we can use `ConditionalExpression` to force selection of a real inverse:

```
 Plot[ InverseFunction[
         ConditionalExpression[ 
           1 - 0.6*CDF[NormalDistribution[1, 0.3], #] - 
               0.4*CDF[NormalDistribution[3, 0.3], #], Element[#, Reals] ] &] @
              x , {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Btw, can we do operations it, like Plot[D[x*InverseFunction[
     ConditionalExpression[
       1 - 0.6*CDF[NormalDistribution[1, 0.3], #] - 
        0.4*CDF[NormalDistribution[3, 0.3], #], Element[#, Reals]] &]@
    x, x], {x, 0, 1}] It seems it doesn't work. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

```
f[x_] = 1 -
   0.6*CDF[NormalDistribution[1, 0.3], x] -
   0.4*CDF[NormalDistribution[3, 0.3], x];

ParametricPlot[{f[x], x}, {x, -1, 3},
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Bob, Thanks for your help. I will frequently use this function in the later analysis and same problem occurs in more complex functions.

Answer (score 5):

To start with, this should not be a problem for Mathematica. The non-inverse function is reasonably well-behaved:

```
f[u_] := 1-0.6 CDF[NormalDistribution[1, 0.3], u] - 0.4 CDF[NormalDistribution[3, 0.3], u];
Plot[f[u], {u, -1, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

(and one can verify, plotting or otherwise, that `f'` remains $<0$ so that `f` is 1-to-1). All I can suggest is to increase `PlotPoints`:

```
g = InverseFunction[f];
Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 4}, PlotPoints -> 30000]
```

nearly fills the gap around .3 but does nothing below .2, and takes over 400 sec here :(.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You may want to report it to Wolfram.

Comment: You could try increasing MaxRecursion instead of this huge number of points, might help a bit.

Comment: LOL so many plot points.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries The plot starts getting a bit better at 10000 points, there is a definite improvement between 20k and 30k. MaxRecursion->5 did not help.